# Issue downloading HTML form data as a xml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, forms

I'm trying to download data from a html form and save said data as a XML file. I found a tutorial on how to do this with JS online but I'm having some issues implementing it successfully.

When i click "Create File" i see the desired output display briefly in the textarea but then immediately disappear as the page refreshes, and i can not get the download button to work. if any one can advice me on how to get the XMLto remain in the textarea and how to make the download button work that would be great.thank you.

tutorial with working example of what m trying to implement
http://jsbin.com/xusekaqoma/edit?html,js,output

JavaScript

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.4.1/processing-api.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">

</script>

<script>

        $(function () {
      $('#DownloadButton').click(update);
    });

    var template = [
      '<?xml version="1.0"?>',
      '<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">',
      '...',
      '<Satisfaction><?Satisfaction?></Satisfaction>',
      '...',
      '<FutureProducts><?FutureProducts?></FutureProducts>',
      '...',
       '<HearAboutCompany><?HearAboutCompany?></HearAboutCompany>',
       '...',
       '<Contact><?Contact?></Contact>',
       '...',
       '<Promotions><?Promotions?></Promotions>',
       '...',
      '</unattend>'
    ].join('\r\n');

    function update() {
      var variables = {
        'Satisfaction': $('#Satisfaction').val(),
        'FutureProducts': $('#FutureProducts').val(),
        'HearAboutCompany': $('#HearAboutCompany').val(),
        'Contact': $('#Contact').val(),
        'Promotions': $('#Promotions').val()
      };

      var newXml = template.replace(/<\?(\w+)\?>/g,
        function(match, name) {
          return variables[name];
        });


      $('#ResultXml').val(newXml);
      $('#DownloadLink')
        .attr('href', 'data:text/xml;base64,' + btoa(newXml))
        .attr('download', 'autounattended.xml');
      <!-- $('#generated').show(); -->
    }

    if (!window.btoa) {
      // Source: http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid78168FE1380F7420FB7B7CD8BAEAE58929523C17.aspx
      btoa = function (input) {
        var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

        var result = '';
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        do {
          chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
          chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
          chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

          enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
          enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
          enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
          enc4 = chr3 & 63;

          if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
          } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
          }

          result += chars.charAt(enc1) + chars.charAt(enc2) + chars.charAt(enc3) + chars.charAt(enc4);
        } while (i < input.length);

        return result;
      };
    }

</script>
```

html

```
<div id ="main">


        <form action ="" name = "myForm" class = "contact" >

        <h3>Please take a moment to fill out this short survey </h3></br>

        <label>
        <span>Satisfaction with service</span></br>

        <select id="Satisfaction">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3" >3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
        </select></br>

        </label>
        <label>
        <span>Future products your intrested in?</span></br>

        <select id="FutureProducts">
                <option value="Smartwatch">Smart Watch</option>
                <option value="VirtualRealitydevices">Virtual Reality devices</option>

        </select></br>

        </label>            
        <label>
        <span>How did you hear about the company?</span></br>

        <select id="HearAboutCompany">
                <option value="friend">friend</option>
                <option value="online">online</option>
                <option value="local">local advertisement</option>

        </select></br>
        </label>


        <label>
        <span>Preferred means of contact</span></br>

        <select id="Contact">
                <option value="mobile">mobile</option>
                <option value="post">post</option>
                <option value="email">email</option>

        </select></br>

        </label>


        <label>
        <span>Do you wish to be contacted about future promotions ?</span></br>


          <select id="Promotions">
                <option value="yes">yes</option>
                <option value="no">no</option>


        </select></br>


         <button id="DownloadButton">Create file</button>

        </label>

        </form>

          <div id="generated" style="">
        <h2>autounattended.xml</h2>
            <a href="#" id="DownloadLink">Download</a>
            <textarea id="ResultXml" style="width: 100%; height: 30em" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
        </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` element have a default behaviour similar to `<input type="submit"/>` which will submit form automatically.
Try `<button type="button">`

Comment: Worked perfectly Thank you